# multiple tasks on tkinter canvas?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to update canvas background at the same time running a binding event.

(from code)In `do_popup` popup menu will be implemented and `conti` will continuously change the canvas background color. how can i use popup option while canvas is updating continuously.

Sample code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def do_popup(event,w2):
    print w2 # inplace of print some popupmenu will be implemented
def conti():
    idt=1
    while idt==1:
        w.config(bg="red") # in place of red it will be a random color
        w.update_idletasks()
w= Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
line1 = w.create_line(200,200,300,300, width=10, tags="line1", fill="black")
w.tag_bind(line1, "<Button-3>", lambda e, w2="test1" :do_popup(e,w2))
f = Frame(root)
f.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
f1=Button(f, text='visual', command=lambda :conti())
f1.grid(row=0, column=1,columnspan=1, sticky=W+N+S+E)
mainloop()
```

will multiprocessing work? 
I am using windows 7 32 bit with python 2.7.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When your script enters the mainloop then the events are executed.

To make reoccurring updates I like to do this:

```
def conti():
    try:
        w.config(bg="red") # in place of red it will be a random color
    finally:
        # start conti after 10 milliseconds, 
        root.after(10, conti) 
        # could also be 0ms to handle events
root.after(0, conti)
```

You can see `root.mainloop` as

```
while not (root.quit was called):
    root.update()
```

This way wou can do:

```
root.quit()
```

and `conti` automatically stops.

There is no concurrency as with threads in `mainloops`.
But you can put a mainloop() somewhere when you create an own dialog box and `conti` will go on.
If you use the modules `tkMessageBox`(Python2) or `tkinter.messagebox`(Python3) then you `conti` should run while the dialog is open.

Does this answer your questions?

PS: do `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)` to make the mainloop end when you close the window.